# Delay in event listeners added to Google Markers

Tags: angular, google-maps, zone

I have a Google Map with 10 markers on it and an Angular2 SideNav added to the page like this:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <div id="map">Google Map [Code omitted]</div>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav position="end" align="end" class="user-sidenav"></mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>`
```

In my component I have:

```ts
@ViewChild(MatSidenav) sidenav: MatSidenav;
// ...
```

Each marker has an event listener added to it with the following code:

```ts
google.maps.event.addListener(gmr, 'click', (function(marker) {
   return function() {
      self.handleMarkerClick(marker);
   };
})(gmr));
```

`gmr` is a `google.maps.Marker` and `self` = `this`

`handleMarkerClick` looks like this:

```ts
private handleMarkerClick(marker: any) {
    this.sidenav.open();
    console.log('sidenav open');
}
```

The only thing it does is opens an Angular Material Sidenav. After I click on a marker there is a delay of 2-3 seconds before the sidenav is opened. With the help of `console.log()` I can see that 'sidenav open' is printed the same instant I click on the marker, but the sidenav animation starts 2-3 seconds later.

Just for testing purposes, I've added a button to my HTML:

```html
<button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Open sidenav</button>
```

And sidenav opens instantly with this.

Does anyone have a clue why there is a delay in opening the sidenav from a component but not from HTML?

Edit: delay ranges from 1 to 3 seconds. Sometimes it's faster, sometimes it's slow.

Edit2: I have done another test and came up with a custom sidenav solution (some html, animations, etc. which basically replicates Angular Material sidenav). And it's still slow when invoked from the component, so it's not Angular Material issue. Any clues?

Comment: Can you show us your **full code**? It might help.

Comment: Edric, this is the only code responsible for the sidenav. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Turns out it didn't have anything to do with Angular Material, but with event listeners added to Google markers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what was going on.

First thing I've done is re-written code which adds even listeners to google markers like this:

```
gmr.addListener('click', () => {
    this.handleMarkerClick(gmr);
});
```

Then I noticed that a lot of things are going on with Zone.js. I didn't have a clue what was it.

> A Zone is an execution context that persists across async tasks. You
>   can think of it as thread-local storage for JavaScript VMs. [from github.com/angular/zone.js]

Turns out the UI wouldn't update properly, because `sidenav` (which is updated in `handleMarkerClick()`) is updated outside of Angular's zone. So we have to include `this.zone.run` in order to get the correct updates:

```
gmr.addListener('click', () => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.handleMarkerClick(gmr);
    });
});
```

`NgZone` needs to be included from `'@angular/core'` and `zone` variable added in class constructor.

Maps are flying now and event handlers toggle sidenav panel with no lag at all.